# How to fold all blocks below certain level in emacs org-mode?

Tags: emacs, org-mode, block, fold

I often need to see information up to (down to, really) certain level of detail. Is there a way to unfold blocks to a certain level, and hide the rest? For example:

```
* name
Joe
** home number
111-111-1111
*** hobby
fishing
*** likes
books
** work number
222-222-2222
```

If third-level and below blocks are rarely used, then I would like to see them folded as such:

```
* name
Joe
** home number
111-11-1111
*** hobby...
*** likes...
** work number
222-22-2222
```

Comment: Perhaps those items that are not often used or wanted to be seen should be listed as PROPERTIES in a DRAWER?

Comment: This is pretty close to what I want. But: (1) it's a bit verbose to use, and (2) it does not follow block hierarchy and behavior (so folding/unfolding up to a certain level cannot be done). Lastly, (3) collapsed drawer shows up simply as :PROPERTIES:. This is not nice, it does not give any indication of what's inside. It does not tell me at a glance that "hobby" is stored there.

Comment: blocks and sections are different animals. Here's an answer for **blocks** : https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/30504/13477

Answer (score 12):

There's `hide-sublevels`.  The exact number to use for the level you need will typically vary depending on the major mode, tho.  I usually use `C-1 M-x hide-sublevels` (aka `C-1 C-c C-q`), but for some major modes I use much deeper levels.

Comment: hide-sublevels if only marginally useful as it keeps the blocks folded while hiding both lower-level blocks and the higher-level block's contents. By example above, the phone numbers won't be visible after C-3 M-x hide-sublevels.

Answer (score 3):

If you place the cursor at the beginning of the buffer, a simple `<TAB>` will cycle the visibility of the entire subtree.

Alternatively, calling it with a prefix argument will set the global subtree visibility to the  depth specified by the argument (`C-u <TAB>`).  For example; `C-u 3 <TAB>` would show everything up to the third level of the tree and hide everything below that.

Also see http://orgmode.org/manual/Visibility-cycling.html#Visibility-cycling

Comment: I actually did bother to read the manual. This does not work. Can you try the example I gave? Correction: by "does not work" I mean it does not do what I want to do (see my question).